# Android event after orientation changed

Tags: android, events, listview, orientation, listener

I have this problem for over a week now and after going through dozens of topics here and on google, I still don't have an answer.
The issue is that I am dynamically loading data to long ListView, so the initialization doesn't last for ages. After changing phone orientation ListView is beeing resized and have empty elements inside (thats ok). So i thought that OnConfigurationChanged event will handle this. Unfortunately it's fired before widgeds are resized, so still I have empty list. And here is my question: Is it anyway to get an event (or Listener) that will fore after the widged is resized and drawn?

I already have in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize
```

And there is no way to turn it "off", because loading takes few seconds and I don't want to have a few seconds lag while chenging phone orientation.

P.S. Sorry for any language mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes. You can use setOnGlobalLayoutListener() that will listen and you use a callback once layout is completed

Also on screen rotation, activity should be destroyed, recreate, so your loading should restart. Are you doing something strange?

I do this in one of my fragment :

```
root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking_accepted, null);
    root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Dbg.e(TAG, "- On Layout Completed ! ");
                    // If you need this to be called again, then run again addOnGlobalLayoutListener.
                    // root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    isLayoutCompleted = true;
                    // YOU write here all the coed you might need. }}}} close brackets
```

Edit :

1. Most people think it's horrible to not let android do its job: destroy and recreate when screen rotates. But you can do what you want.
2. Loading an empty list view is very light. It's impossible it takes few seconds to load the layout. You HAVE to load the layout and your listview with a spinner to let the user know what his phone is doing (loading). Once data is loaded, notify data change to the adapter.

does it change your point of view? ask me, if I know, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working. The callback is still running before ListView change it's size.

Comment: Are you letting the activity be destroyed and recreated? Have you override OnConfigurationChange?

Comment: No, I don't let it be destroyed and recreated, because like I said in first post (just after you answered) it will be causing a few seconds lag while changing phones orientation.
And yes, I've overrided OnConfigurationChange and this it's too running before ListView is redrawn.